# twitter PWA doesn't open in native-app like setting

Tags: ios, twitter, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I am new to PWA and super excited about this. Sorry, this question is not technical at all, but I wanted to demo a successful PWA in the market to people at my work. And I have saved twitter to my home screen on my iPhone, and when I click it on the home screen to open the PWA, it automatically opens in safari browser.. 
Can someone please tell me how I can open twiter app in PWA? 
To make sure it's not my phone's problem, I saved the below PWA on my phone and this opens as a native app like setting: https://angular2-hn.firebaseapp.com/news/1

Thanks so much and sorry for asking stupid non-technical question here...
I googled everywhere but couldn't find a similar question being asked anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [blog](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/native-apps-are-doomed-ac397148a2c0), in order to use PWA, make sure that you have met the specific criteria:

- Must be HTTPS (see [let’s encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/))
- Valid manifest with required properties ([Web Manifest Validator](https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/))
- Must have service worker
- Manifest `start_url` must always load, even offline (using service worker)
- Must supply its own navigation
- Should be responsive to different screen sizes and orientations

Hope this helps.

Comment: The service worker also needs a fetch event handler. It does not need to do anything, but it needs to be there. The browser is looking to see 'if the site could work offline'. Since they cannot evaluate your logic to verify without doing a full lighthouse type eval, it just looks for the event handler presence.